# Connection to nodejs (express) refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, connection-refused

I’m a long term programmer, but haven’t used nodejs much in my code. Now I need to use it in my current code and I’ve ran into a problem that I can’t seem to figure out myself, I have googled a lot but nothing seem to fix it.

I am trying to get my website to connect to the nodejs server running on same host.

If I visit the url in my browser, it works fine `(http://localhost:6857/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling)` and I see this respond

```
0{"sid":"s_v860SbNO4toknPAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
```

But when I try to connect thru the website, I just get

```
GET http://localhost:6857/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N_gL_HZ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Can someone guide my in the right direction for how to fix this, so I can begin using nodejs inside my website?

This is my server.js

```
// use express
var express = require("express");
 
// create instance of express
var app = express();


 
// use http with instance of express
var http = require("http").createServer(app);

// start the server
var port = 6857;
http.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log("Listening to port " + port);
});

// create socket instance with http
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

// add listener for new connection
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // this is socket for each user
    console.log("User connected", socket.id);
});

io.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

And this is my JS code inside my website

```
<script>
    var server = "http://localhost:6857/";
    var io = io(server);
</script>
```

Comment: The same is if I visit http://localhost:6857/socket.io/socket.io.js int he browser, then I can fine reveive it, however if I use <script src="http://localhost:6857/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> then it can’t be found.

This is btw the guide I’ve been using: https://adnan-tech.com/realtime-web-based-chat-in-node-js-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket IO requires you to enable CORS explicitly - Thus why you get the error stated above.

To enable CORS, please see the following [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiply cors fixes, none seem to work. But shouldn't be needed when it localhost, I do get the cors error if I use domain instead, but no cors setting seem to have helped, I will try again with the link you posted and report back in a bit.

Comment: Can see I already had that in my code, this is current code: https://pastebin.com/guiW01Py - but I still get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://socket.domain.tld:6857/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_gsTul' from origin 'https://dash.domain.tld' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Socket IO requires you to explicitly enable CORS. See: https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Comment: I owe you a large beer at the airport mate, that was the fix I was looking for, thank you very much. If you can edit your answer to add this link and text, then I will add it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it worked out - No problem :-)

Comment: I've been on this site for years and no-ones ever offered me a large airport beer. Take it, @JeppeChristensen, while the offer is still good.